# How to reorder JQuery UI tabs programatically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I have jQuery tabs as shown in the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vF5kN5?p=preview) and i want to write a function to reorder tabs, this function can reorder other elements as well other than tab, Basically i will pass the arguments like this, it will take two arguments

1) element
2) nextSibling: the element to come after the passed element

```
function reorder(element, nextSibling){
    //I want to move the element here
}
```

So, How to identify the passed element is jQuery tab and how to  reorder.

Please refer to the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vF5kN5?p=preview) link to see the jQuery tabs

Here we are following an convention that we added attributes to tab content 'xe-section' and corresponding tab heading with 'xe-for-section', both the attribute values will be same.

here is the code snippet

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li xe-for-section="fragment-1"><a href="#fragment-1"><span>One</span></a></li>
    <li xe-for-section="fragment-2"><a href="#fragment-2"><span>Two</span></a></li>
    <li xe-for-section="fragment-3"><a href="#fragment-3"><span>Three</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="fragment-1" xe-section ="fragment-1">
    Tab 1
  </div> 
  <div id="fragment-2" xe-section="fragment-2">
    Tab 2
  </div>
  <div id="fragment-3" xe-section="fragment-3">
    Tab 3
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();


function reorder(element, nextSibling){
//Example: element= fragment-2, nextSibling = fragment-1 

// I want to reorder tabs here    

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/ss6UatsYVaFokKejMBR5?p=preview).
You need to use [insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) and use the "[xe-for-section="fragment-3"]"-selector

```
reorder($('[xe-for-section="fragment-3"]'), $('[xe-for-section="fragment-2"]'));

function reorder(element, nextSibling) {
    if(element.attr('role') === 'tab' && nextSibling.attr('role') === 'tab') {
        element.insertBefore(nextSibling);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats okay But how to identify the element is TAB, See my full post, I can reorder any other element also

Comment: You could check if the elements you send to the function are children of <div id="tabs"> with:
if(element.parents('#tabs').eq(0).length && nextSibling.parents('#tabs').eq(0).length) { ... }

Comment: Id can change right, So we can one more tab with #tab2, In this case, it fails, How to check any element passed is tab

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to identify the tab based on the classes dynamically added by the jQuery like .ui-tab-panel and any classes

Comment: Ahh sure - i totally forgot that ^^. Se my edit (+plunker) above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66107/discussion-between-vinay-and-ferret).

Comment: Is that role='tab' is an mandatory field added by jquery UI, i can't see one such in my website, Is that added by newer versions of jquery UI

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.7.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.15/jquery-ui.js"></script>

This jquery and UI combination does no add the role='tab'

Comment: Its added after your pageLoad dynamically via JS. So you need to rightclick->"inspect element" (or F12 and search) so see that changes.
Check the plunker-script above to see that its there and working.